# JavaScript object property with `get` accessor not in Object.keys()

Tags: javascript, key

Let's say I have a class with a public property with only a `get` accessor. I want to be able to loop through the object keys to process the object.

```js
class Foo {
    get bar() {
        return 'barval';
    }
}
```

Why is `bar` not visible when I call `Object.keys(...)` (or similar functions) or looping through the keys in an object? `foo.bar` successfully returns `barval` when requested, but `Object.keys(foo)` returns an empty array when I expected it to return `["bar"]`. Why is this?

**Sample output:**

```js
const foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.bar,            // barval
    Object.keys(foo),           // []
    Object.entries(foo),        // []
    Object.values(foo));        // []
for (let key in foo)
    console.log(key, foo[key]); // Never reached
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class getters and setters aren't properties of the class instance so they aren't available in `keys`, `entries` or `values`.

They are instead members of the object’s prototype. You can iterate through the prototype, and just remove the likes of `constructor` to leave you with just those which you have declared in your class.

As far as I'm aware, the only way to do this would be:

```js
class Foo {
    get bar() {
        return 'barval';
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();

for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo))) {
    console.log(prop);
}
```

Returns:

```
constructor
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors) instead.

```js
class Foo {
    get bar() {
        return 'barval';
    }
}
let o = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Foo.prototype);
console.log(o);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question